# how to fix Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java

how to fix this problem?

public class Binary {
static public Student Search(Student[] arr, String key, int left, int right){

```
    int mid = left + (right - left)/2;

    if(arr[mid].Surname == key){
        if(arr[mid].Academic_debt == "4") {
            Student temp = arr[mid];
            arr[mid] = null;
            return temp;
        }
        return null;
    }

    else if(arr[mid].Surname > key){
        return Search(arr,key ,left, (mid - 1));
    }
    else{
        return Search(arr,key ,(mid + 1), right);
    }
}

static public void Show(Student[] arr){
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.println( ++k + ": " + arr[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use something like `arr[mid].Surname.compareTo(key) > 0`

Comment: Also, see [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).